# conda-build doesn't install requirements

Tags: python, package, conda, snakemake, conda-build

I am trying to built a simple conda package with one dependency ([snakemake](https://anaconda.org/bioconda/snakemake)) using `conda-build` command. My `meta.yaml` file is:

```
package:
        name: Foo
        version: "0.0.1"

source:
        git_url: <Foo Github project URL>

requirements:
        build:
            - snakemake

        run:
            - snakemake

 about:
        home: <Foo project homepage URL>
```

My build command:

```
cd foo_package
conda-build --python 3.6 --debug .
```

The package was built successfully. However, after installing the package to a new Conda enviroment and trying to run `snakemake` command from the dependent package, I get `command not found` error and the `snakemake` package is not installed.

How should I change my built to actually include the `snakemake` conda package?

System: Ubuntu 20.04
Conda version: 4.8.4

Comment: Not sure this is the issue, but the formatting of the YAML as shown in the question is not valid YAML (maybe just be a typo here?). Be aware that the YAML spec is whitespace sensitive, so ensure that the indentation (spaces only - no tabs) follows [the example](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html).